# Are the Cell juniors being alive from the manga bonus "special" drawn by Toyotaro supposed to be canon?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-manga

So Toyotaro drew a Dragon Ball Super manga bonus "special" which he showed in the Jump Victory Carnival and where the Cell juniors killed in the Cell saga are supposed to be alive and living in 17's island. Is this supposed to be canon manga or promotional manga?

> .[image]

Comment: sometimes specials are drawn and published out of order of the main story events, worth keeping that in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is canon.

> In the manga, After **seemingly** being killed by Gohan, the Cell Juniors managed to **regenerate** through their intact nuclei, and were tamed by Android 17 to defend Monster Island and not attack rangers.

[Source](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Cell_Jr.)